# Web Application Project is configured to use IIS but The Web server could not be found - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

I know there's a ton of SO questions on this same topic but I've been unable to fix using any of their solutions.

My environment got jacked up so I deleted everything and got latest from source control.

When loading up the sln all projects load fine except the web project which does not load at all, giving me the error

> C:\Tungsten\Tungsten\Tungsten.web\Tungsten.web.csproj : error  : The Web Application Project Tungsten.web is configured to use IIS.  The Web server 'http://localhost:2025/' could not be found.

1. My .csproj has UseIISExpress set to false, and UseIIS set to true
2. I deleted my .csproj.user file

Including relevant bits from .csproj

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>2025</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:2025/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
```

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{D671F45E-5436-448C-9B10-664DA296095A}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Tungsten.web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Tungsten.web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can you include the content of your Tungsten.web.csproj -file?

Comment: @MikaelKoskinen added